# Separate git repo for one folder in another git repo

Tags: git

This is my project folder structure. I am using GitLab as my repo site. I am using Git `v2.17.1`.

[image: Folder structure]

I have multiple such projects which have the same structure. In all of them, the `src` folder should be the same. Is it possible to create a separate git repo for `src` and link it to this repo and the others? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

**What are Submodules?**

The concept of submodules is brilliant. It essentially allows you to attach an external repository inside another repository at a specific path

**How to use it?**

1. Create a separate repo for your `src` folder.
2. Add the `src` repo to your every repo that use it:

`git submodule add git@mygithost:src localpath/when/submodule/will/be`

3. load the content of the submodule repo:

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

4. If you want to clone the repo with the submodule repo (`src` repo) use this command:

`git clone --recursive [URL to Git repo]`